# Frequent rpc_timeouts of the query SELECT count(*) FROM Keyspace1.Standard1 limit 5; in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have a 5 node cassandra cluster with 3 nodes on a private DC & the other 2 on AWS.

Select * requests are timing out even when it is limited to 5. I understand if they are timing out for high numbers but timing out for single digits looks strange strange. 
Any one observed this before?
NOTE: Queries with WHERE clause are normal.

Answer (score 1):

There are two or three options:

1) Your servers are too busy / slow to reply to the query.

2) You're hitting a tombstone exception, which sometimes doesn't get reported properly. Check the log on the cassandra server for the word 'tombstone' to be sure.

3) You're asking for too much data at once - less likely if it happens when you LIMIT 5.

I'm guessing it's #2. Look for tombstone warnings in your cassandra server logs. If that's the problem, you likely have a data model problem.

Comment: I guess you were right. running a nodetool repair solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are the nodes on two different networks (you said private DC and AWS), check if the communication between nodes.

what is the consistency you are using when querying, try with consistency of one and see the response and then checkthe communication between nodes (with higher consistency it always checks the consistency of data with other nodes before responding back with results).

Does your select have any where clause or a simple select *, if later then again retrieving data from different nodes with a slow inter node communication might be an issue.